# Php Get & Post with Google App Engine

Tags: php, regex, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I uploaded my files to my google app engine instance and have successfully have been able to connect to the database and pull data.  However, I am trying to pull specific data with a GET request by appending variables to the URL.  I am try calling the URL (with my app name changed here for security) http://MYAPP.appspot.com/getCategories?catId=1 and I use a get request to grab the category id which is appended on the end.  I believe the issue is with my app.yaml file since everything keeps defaulting to my catch all at the bottom.  However, on my local instance it works just fine.  How can I change my app.yaml file so I can make sure it triggers the first instance /getCategories.php instead of index.php?  Do I need to write regular expression to account of the data being appended to the end?

```
#app.yaml
application: MYAPP
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /getCategories.php
  script: /getCategories.php

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

Answer (score 2):

The URL you are tring to access is `http://MYAPP.appspot.com/getCategories?catId=1`. But there is no handler for `getCategories`. So it always goes to the default handler `index.php`

As per your app.yaml, Your URL should be `http://MYAPP.appspot.com//getCategories.php?catId=1`

Or if you need your url as it is, Then you should modify the app.yaml handler to

```
- url: /getCategories
  script: /getCategories.php
```

Comment: So since I don't know if the catId with be 1, 2 or whatever number, how do I create a handler to make sure it catches `http://MYAPP.appspot.com//getCategories.php?catId=1` no matter what the last number is on the end?

Comment: `catId` is the URL parameter. The above handler will handle it. So all the request comes to `getCategories.php` will be handled by the script. And you can get `catId` value by `$_GET["catId"]`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nijin, but I would also add:

Whilst you only have a handler to match your index (a catch all -url:/.* with script: index.php), all this will do is catch ALL requests to any page and route them to the index file (which is good as a fallback or can be used as an error catch). That said, Nijin indicated you need a route for your /getCategories.php script, which is fine, except you will end up with thinking you need one for every single page you write. Better idea is to create a url/script handler that catches the typed (or linked) url in the address bar and matches it to a php file on disk that GAE should serve. The catch all (-url:/.*) should go LAST in the app.yaml so you don't miss anything, and route them back to the index page if they type something incorrectly. Hence:

```
handlers:
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

Hope that makes sense!

Cheers.